# R - Behaviour of '==' when subsetting data.frame with NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a seemingly simple question that I'm trying to figure out.

Consider this example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A", "B", NA, "C"), Value=c(1,2,3,4))
df$ID[df$ID %in% "A"]
```

Returns `A` (as expected)

But:

```
df$ID[df$ID == "A"]
```

Returns `A <NA>`.

I know I can remove the NA value by using `df$ID[df$ID == "A" & !is.na(df$ID)]` , but could someone explain me why the NA value is included in the output at all? Does it have something do with the type of data? I tried converting the column ID to character, but that solve the issue.

Comment: `==` returns `NA` as `NA` while `%in%` returns FALSE.  Converting the ID to character class will return the NA

Comment: Thank you, but what's the rationale behind this? Why does `==` return `NA`?

Comment: You can check the NA handling [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#NA-handling)

Comment: You can also use `df$ID[which(df$ID == "A")]` because `which()` drops NA values. You can also read the `?match` help page (where `%in%` is documented) to see the discussion of how it choose to treat NA values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `df$ID == "A"` returns a logical vector. When comparing a logical statement like this to an NA value (the third value in your df$ID column), it doesn't return false, because its NA. `is.na()` is what is used for logical vectors relating to `NA`. So if we do just `df$ID == "A"` we get:

```
df$ID == "A"
[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA FALSE
```

So now if you want to subset the column df$ID, by this logical vector, you're subsetting everything that's true. But it will also give you back `NA`s if there are any. (Same when you use the sum function, it will return summed numbers, and `NA`s if you have any, which prompts the use of `na.rm = TRUE` to remove them from the sum function.

This is why `df$ID[df$ID == "A"]` returns both `A` and `<NA>`

```
df$ID[df$ID == "A"]
[1] A    <NA>
Levels: A B C
```